# PacMan on Google homepage, how is it implemented?

Tags: javascript, pacman

I was wondering, how was the PacMan game on Google.com implemented?

Javascript?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884064/howto-download-local-copy-of-googles-pacman-game

Answer (score 27, accepted):

JavaScript with HTML for the graphics (no canvas, but sprite divs etc). There is also a bit of flash for the music.

Here is the master sprite:
[image]

Comment: I may disagree with their methods from time to time, but the people at Google are some serious studs.

Comment: Yea, considering the time invested into this. They are truly awesome when if comes to doing things differently! But again, I am also not a big fan of Google!

Comment: makes me want to program a platform game in javascript...

Answer (score 6):

I had a quick look at the Google homepage HTML, and found a link to this JavaScript script:

[`/logos/js/pacman10-hp.3.js`](http://www.google.ch/logos/js/pacman10-hp.3.js)

So I'd say yes, it's implemented in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.google.co.uk/logos/js/pacman10-hp.3.js) is the complete javascript code. You might want to run it through a [Javascript Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). It's too long to post here.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884064/howto-download-local-copy-of-googles-pacman-game/2886890#2886890

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Javascript and Html. A rewritten version can be found on [GitHub](http://github.com/macek/google_pacman).